# using protobuf reflection to get a boolean field descriptor in c++

Tags: c++, reflection, protocol-buffers, descriptor

I am using grpc in a C++ application.  On the client side, I need to reflectively query a boolean value from a message using reflection.

The response message is shown below.  Unfortunately I cannot see field descriptors for the bool mAP field - I can however see the FieldDescriptors for the string fields,  What am I doing wrong?

John

```
message Response {
    // OTP Connection Status
    enum OTPConnStatus {
        Disconnected              = 0;
        Connected                 = 1;
        InvalidCS                 = 2;
        DiscRequest               = 3;
    }

    // define the fields
    RXMessageType mMessageType    = 1;
    bool mAP                      = 2;
    OTPConnStatus mCS1            = 3;
    OTPConnStatus mCS2            = 4;
    OTPConnStatus mCS3            = 5;
    OTPConnStatus mCS4            = 6;
    string mOTP1                  = 7;
    string mOTP2                  = 8;
    string mOTP3                  = 9;
    string mOTP4                  = 10;
}
```

```
const auto reflection = pMessage->GetReflection();
std::vector<const FieldDescriptor*> fields;
pMessage->GetReflection()->ListFields(*pMessage, &fields);
const auto fieldIter = std::find_if(fields.cbegin(), fields.cend(),
    [&lcFieldName](const FieldDescriptor* next) {
        return boost::iequals(next->name(), lcFieldName);
    });
if (fieldIter != fields.cend()) {
    std::string result;
    auto fieldDescriptor = *fieldIter;
    if (!fieldDescriptor->is_repeated()) {
        switch (fieldDescriptor->cpp_type()) {
        case FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_INT32:
            result = std::to_string(reflection->GetInt32 (
                *pMessage, fieldDescriptor));
            break;
        case FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_INT64:
            result = std::to_string(reflection->GetInt64 (
                *pMessage, fieldDescriptor));
            break;
        case FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_UINT32:
            result = std::to_string(reflection->GetUInt32 (
                *pMessage, fieldDescriptor));
            break;
        case FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_UINT64:
            result = std::to_string(reflection->GetUInt64 (
                *pMessage, fieldDescriptor));
            break;
        case FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_DOUBLE:
            result = std::to_string(reflection->GetDouble (
                *pMessage, fieldDescriptor));
            break;
        case FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_FLOAT:
            result = std::to_string(reflection->GetFloat (
                *pMessage, fieldDescriptor));
            break;
        case FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_BOOL:
            result = reflection->GetBool(
                *pMessage, fieldDescriptor) ?
                "true" : "false";
            break;
        case FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_ENUM:
            result = reflection->GetEnum(
                *pMessage, fieldDescriptor)->
                    full_name();
            break;
        case FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_STRING:
            result = reflection->GetString(
                *pMessage, fieldDescriptor);
            break;
        case FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_MESSAGE:
            //result = reflection->GetMessage(
            //    *pMessage, fieldDescriptor);
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    exit(0);
} else {
```

EDIT: I found a utility in the protobuf used to print messages which I used to print the contents.  Here are the results:

```
const auto reflection = pMessage->GetReflection();
std::string formatted;
pb::TextFormat::PrintToString(*pMessage, &formatted);
std::cout << formatted;
```

Printed:

```
mMessageType: OneTimePassword
mOTP1: "TAILNO1"
mOTP2: "TAILNO2"
mOTP3: "TAILNO3"
mOTP4: "TAILNO4"
```

Also, note that the Boolean field in question 'map' is being set by the server.  Looking at the generated `CAService.pb.h` code and comparing the `MessageType` (which does have a working field descriptor) to the `mAP` field which does not, may be useful to protobuf users to show me the error in my approach.

```
// optional .ca.RXMessageType mMessageType = 1;
inline void OTPResponse::clear_mmessagetype() {
  mmessagetype_ = 0;
}
inline ::ca::RXMessageType OTPResponse::mmessagetype() const {
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(field_get:ca.OTPResponse.mMessageType)
  return static_cast< ::ca::RXMessageType >(mmessagetype_);
}
inline void OTPResponse::set_mmessagetype(::ca::RXMessageType value) {

  mmessagetype_ = value;
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(field_set:ca.OTPResponse.mMessageType)
}

// optional bool mAP = 2;
inline void OTPResponse::clear_map() {
  map_ = false;
}
inline bool OTPResponse::map() const {
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(field_get:ca.OTPResponse.mAP)
  return map_;
}
inline void OTPResponse::set_map(bool value) {

  map_ = value;
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(field_set:ca.OTPResponse.mAP)
}
```

Comment: Does it show when you print all the field names? Could it get renamed for some strange reason? Why do you use case insensitive equals in the name filter?

Comment: @StefanHaustein The result of ListFields gives me 5 field descriptors - one for the mMessageType  and the remaining 4 string fields mOTP1-4.  members are by default in lowercase is why I use case insensitive comparison.  Also the lcFieldName is passed in by a user on a keyboard.

Comment: Reflection::ListFields lists only the fields that are set, could that explain the omission of the boolean and enum fields?

Comment: @StefanHaustein good suggestion, however unfortunately that is not the case, I edited the question to show additional printout and generated code  contrasting a field that does have a descriptor against this mAP field does not.  Hopefully that will be useful. Thanks

Comment: Things I would try: 1. Set the bool field locally to the non-default value just before printing the field names via GetReflection. 2. List the field names using the message descriptor instead of GetReflection

Comment: @StefanHaustein excellent suggestion, if I locally set the value of the bool to true in the client before calling the reflection code (I'm guessing the default is false) then the property for this mAP appears, If instead I set it to false (the default value) then the field descriptor disappears.  I'm nt sure what you mean by list the field names using the message descriptor.  Could you point me to such an example or write a one liner? Thanks.

Comment: @StefanHaustein the second suggestion to list the field names shows the field regardless of whether the field is set or not.  This is very strange behavior but I suppose it works.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Reflection::ListFields()` only lists the fields that are currently set. To iterate all fields or to search for a specific field, use the field access methods in `Descriptor`. You can obtain a message descriptor from the message (or from the `Reflection` object) using `GetDescriptor`.

Comment: Nice one thanks for following up with all the comments!